# can't use mysql count in this query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query right now to grab comments on my website:

```
SELECT a.author_id, 
a.guest_username, 
a.comment_text, 
a.comment_id, 
u.pc_info_public, 
u.distro, 
a.time_posted, 
a.last_edited, 
a.last_edited_time, 
u.username, 
u.user_group, 
u.secondary_user_group, 
u.`avatar`, 
u.`avatar_gravatar`, 
u.`gravatar_email`, 
u.`avatar_uploaded`, 
u.`avatar_gallery`, 
u.pc_info_filled, 
ul.username as username_edited 
FROM `articles_comments` a 
LEFT JOIN `users` u ON a.author_id = u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN `users` ul ON ul.user_id = a.last_edited 
WHERE a.`article_id` = ? ORDER BY a.`comment_id` ASC LIMIT ?
```

I'm trying to add-in a COUNT(l.likes) from a table called "likes" (the "l" being what I name it when doing the ON check).

The problem is, when I add the COUNT in, my query instantly fails with an error like this:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'goltest.a.author_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I've googled and googled and all the examples I can find to fix it don't make sense to me, can someone elaborate on the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you what's wrong: You need to `group by` something, to count how many likes that something has. The grouping is usually done on the primary key on which you're joining the tables.

Comment: Ohh it literally wanted a group by, i must have misread it, cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to accept the answers as well. :)